# JS weird expression : +!!NaN * "" - - [,]

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to understand how to evaluate this expression `+!!NaN * "" - - [,]`

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: @VLAZ mixed with JS quirks :)

Comment: @RoboRobok barely any. Just some conversions. Re-write it to a proper form and it's not that hard to follow.

Comment: Expand each expression tree on the right panel: https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/1ec8a5d88c2d575263aa9046c6c73db9/febcc9acc5155bd7ecab6610f359197b24459820

Comment: @VLAZ multiplying number by string is not a quirk?

Comment: @RoboRobok multiplication always converts both operands to numbers. So, barely a quirk. `s * 1` is a trick that is somewhat popular to convert strings to numbers.

Comment: I have never seen any professional code doing that, that's awful. I wish JS threw errors in cases like that instead of doing some random hocus-pocus.

Comment: @RoboRobok I didn't say it's a *good* practice. Just that it's somewhat popular. A unary plus or using `Number` is much better.

Comment: Yeah, my preferred way is definitely `Number(s)`. But it's interesting I haven't seen this popular way in my almost 20 years with JS.

Comment: @RoboRobok https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056963 https://stackoverflow.com/a/22440945 https://stackabuse.com/javascript-convert-string-to-number just some of the first results I found for "convert string to number javascript"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+!!NaN; // !NaN => true -> !true => false -> +false => 0


Number(""); // -> 0

-[,]; // -> - 0 , [,] is empty so it will be casted to 0
```

Add it all together:

```
0 * 0 - -0; // -> 0
```